# how to know when my await function is over/terminated though a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, async-await, task

I have an `async` method in a *loop*

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task WatermarXabeAsyncBase()
{
    var result = await conversion.Start();
}

...

foreach (var x in y)
{
    WatermarXabeAsyncBase()        
}
```

I want to call another method ONLY when the await function is over.
What should I do and how?

Comment: Its hard to know what you want to achieve here and if you have left out any pertinent information or code (which I think is more than highly likely). However, if you want to run an async method in a loop and await the results. You could do something like this `await Task.WhenAll(y.Select(x => WatermarXabeAsyncBase()))` Then call next method

Comment: I think you really need to view this [ask], and this [mcve] and read this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Why aren't you `await`ing `WatermarXabeAsyncBase()` in the loop? Also, you say "when the await function is over", but what does that mean? I mean, you can place code in `WatermarXabeAsyncBase` after the `await` line, and it will be called after that code has completed. We are talking about programming computers here; we need to be as precise as they are or we risk introducing even worse bugs :).

Comment: Anyway, voting to close as needs detail and clarity

Answer (score 0):

Save returned `Task` and then you can check if it is complete or not by awaiting it.

To wait inside the loop

```
foreach (var x in y)
{
    var task = WatermarXabeAsyncBase();
    // .. do something else

    await task;
    // next lines of code will be executed only after task is complete
    // do something after method is complete
}
```

To wait for all tasks to complete

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var x in y)
{
    var task = WatermarXabeAsyncBase();
    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Do something after all methods are complete.
```